# Very simple example CSS not working

Tags: css, styles

Using CSS, how do I change the color of text inside links (Home, Page Two, Search)?

```
<div id="navBarGoUP" >
   <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page Two</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Search</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

I tried with:

```
#navBarGoUP > ul > li > a{
   color: red;
}
```

But it is not working.

Comment: It works [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jX9hR/)

Comment: Did you include this `CSS`?

Comment: it works check css is included or not  http://jsfiddle.net/Vinay199129/cZCWm/

Comment: It's included. Probably I have overridden the style of some element. I'll check it. I thought that my CSS is not correct.

Comment: @protector Can you post your full CSS?

Comment: It's OK.. It works.. The `<li>` tag was overridden in CSS. I can't post full CSS because it have a lot of lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check [jsFIddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cZCWm/2/)

#### HTML

```
<div id="navBarGoUP">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page Two</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Search</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
div#navBarGoUP > ul > li > a {
    color: red;
}
div#navBarGoUP ul li a:hover, #navBarGoUP ul li a:active {
    color: #e88080;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

ke a look at this

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_link.asp

```
a:link {color:#FF0000;}      /* unvisited link */
  a:visited {color:#00FF00;}  /* visited link */
 a:hover {color:#FF00FF;}  /* mouse over link */
  a:active {color:#0000FF;}  /* selected link */
```